# How can I improve the hierarchy of my event classes?

Tags: oop, events, class, class-hierarchy

For the [XMPP interface for the Stack Overflow chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat/63420#63420) I am parsing the JSON feed from chat and generating Ruby objects for every chat events, such as messages sent, edits sent, users logging in or out, etc. I also generate events for "slash-commands" sent to the XMPP server, like "/help" or "/auth" in order to allow the XMPP user to authenticate with their Stack Overflow chat account.

I have set up these classes in a hierarchy I feel makes good logical sense:

```
class SOChatEvent # base class
 |
 |--- class SOXMPPEvent # base for all events that are initiated via XMPP
 | |
 | |--- class SOXMPPMessage # messages sent to the XMPP bridge via XMPP
 | | |
 | | |--- class SOXMPPMessageToRoom # messages sent from an XMPP user to an XMPP MUC
 | | |
 | | |--- class SOXMPPUserCommand # class for "slash commands", that is, messages starting
 | | | |                          # with /, used for sending commands to the bridge
 | | | |
 | | | |--- class SOXMPPUserHelpCommand
 | | | |--- class SOXMPPUserLoginCommand
 | | | |--- class SOXMPPUserBroadcastCommand
 |
 |--- class SOChatRoomEvent # base class for all events that originate from an SO chat room
 | |
 | |--- class SOChatMessage # messages sent to an SO chat room via the SO chat system
 | | |
 | | |--- class SOChatMessageEdit # edits made to a prior SOChatMessage
 | |
 | |--- class SOChatUserEvent # events related to SO chat users
 | | |
 | | |--- class SOChatUserJoinRoom #Event for when a So user joins a room
 | | |--- class SOChatUserLeaveRoom #Event for when a So user leaves a room

 (etc)
```

You can see the full hierarchy and source [in Trac](http://trac.digitalfruition.com/soxmpp/browser/trunk/classes/SOChatEvents.rb) or [via SVN](https://svn.smart-safe-secure.com/soxmpp/trunk/classes/SOChatEvents.rb).

My question is twofold: First, what is the best way to instantiate these events? What I'm currently doing is parsing the JSON events using a giant `switch` statement --well, it's ruby so it's a `case` statement -- and, it's not giant *yet*, but it will be if I continue this way:

```
rooms.each do |room|
  rid = "r"+"#{room.room_id}"
  if !data[rid].nil?
    @last_update = data[rid]['t'] if data[rid]['t']

    if data[rid]["e"]
      data[rid]["e"].each do |e|
        puts "DEBUG: found an event: #{e.inspect}"
        case e["event_type"]
          when 1
            event = SOChatMessage.new(room,e['user_name'])
            event.encoded_body = e['content']
            event.server = @server
            events.push event
          when 2
            event = SOChatMessageEdit.new(room,e['user_name'])
            event.encoded_body = e['content']
            event.server = @server
            events.push event
          when 3
            user = SOChatUser.new(e['user_id'], e['user_name'])
            event = SOChatUserJoinRoom.new(room,user)
            event.server = @server
            events.push event
          when 4
            user = SOChatUser.new(e['user_id'], e['user_name'])
            event = SOChatUserLeaveRoom.new(room,user)
            event.server = @server
            events.push event
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I imagine there has to be a better way to handle that! Something like `SOChatEvent.createFromJSON( json_data )`... But, what's the best way to structure my code so that objects of the proper subclass are created in response to a given `event_type`?

Second, I'm not actually using ant subclasses of `SOXMPPUserCommand` yet. Right now all commands are just instances of `SOXMPPUserCommand` itself, and that class has a single `execute` method which switches based upon regex of the command. Much the same problem -- I know there's a better way, I just am not sure what the best way is:

```
def handle_message(msg)
    puts "Room \"#{@name}\" handling message: #{msg}"
    puts "message: from #{msg.from} type #{msg.type} to #{msg.to}: #{msg.body.inspect}"

    event = nil

    if msg.body =~ /\/.*/
      #puts "DEBUG: Creating a new SOXMPPUserCommand"
      event = SOXMPPUserCommand.new(msg)
    else
      #puts "DEBUG: Creating a new SOXMPPMessageToRoom"
      event = SOXMPPMessageToRoom.new(msg)
    end

    if !event.nil?
      event.user = get_soxmpp_user_by_jid event.from
      handle_event event
    end
  end
```

and:

```
class SOXMPPUserCommand < SOXMPPMessage
  def execute
    case @body
      when "/help"
        "Available topics are: help auth /fkey /cookie\n\nFor information on a topic, send: /help <topic>"
      when "/help auth"
        "To use this system, you must send your StackOverflow chat cookie and fkey to the system. To do this, use the /fkey and /cookie commands"
      when "/help /fkey"
        "Usage: /fkey <fkey>. Displays or sets your fkey, used for authentication. Send '/fkey' alone to display your current fkey, send '/fkey <something>' to set your fkey to <something>. You can obtain your fkey via the URL: javascript:alert(fkey().fkey)"
      when "/help /cookie"
        "Usage: /cookie <cookie>. Displays or sets your cookie, used for authentication. Send '/cookie' alone to display your current fkey, send '/cookie <something>' to set your cookie to <something>"
      when /\/fkey( .*)?/
        if $1.nil?
          "Your fkey is \"#{@user.fkey}\""
        else
          @user.fkey = $1.strip
          if @user.authenticated?
            "fkey set to \"#{@user.fkey}\". You are now logged in and can send messages to the chat"
          else
            "fkey set to \"#{@user.fkey}\". You must also send your cookie with /cookie before you can chat"
          end
        end
      when /\/cookie( .*)?/
        if $1.nil?
          "Your cookie is: \"#{@user.cookie}\""
        else
          if $1 == " chocolate chip"
            "You get a chocolate chip cookie!"
          else
            @user.cookie = $1.strip
            if @user.authenticated?
              "cookie set to \"#{@user.cookie}\". You are now logged in and can send messages to the chat"
            else
              "cookie set to \"#{@user.cookie}\". You must also send your fkey with /fkey before you can chat"
            end
          end
        end
      else
        "Unknown Command \"#{@body}\""
    end
  end
end
```

I know there's a better way to do this, just not sure what specifically it is. Should the responsibility of creating subclasses of `SOXMPPUserCommand` fall on `SOXMPPUserCommand` itself? Should all subclasses register with the parent? Do I need a new class?

What's the best way to instantiate objects of subclasses in such a hierarchal structure?

Comment: C'mon people! Don't let the ruby scare you off! This should apply to nearly any OOP language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your first question. Here's some ideas you might like to consider

First, structure you sub-classes so they all use the same initiation parameters. Also, you could put some of the other initiating code there as well (such as your encoded_body and server accessors. Here's a skeleton of what I mean:

```
# SOChat Class skeleton structure
class SOChatSubClass  #< inherit from whatever parent class is appropriate
  attr_accessor :encoded_body, :server, :from, :to, :body

  def initialize(event, room, server)
    @encoded_body = event['content']
    @server = server
    SOChatEvent.events.push event

    #class specific code 
    xmpp_message = event['message']
    @from = xmpp_message.from
    @to = xmpp_message.to
    @body = xmpp_message.body
    #use super to call parent class initialization methods and to DRY up your code
  end
end
```

Note that in my example you'll still have duplicated code in the sub-classes. Ideally you'd pull out the duplication by putting it in the appropriate parent class.

If you have problems creating a common list of initiation parameters, then rather than pass in a list of arguments (event, room, server), change the classes to accept an argument list as a hash {:event => event, :room => room, :server => server, etc}.

Regardless, once you have a common parameter structure for initializing the classes, you can initialize them a bit more dynamically, eliminating the need for the case statement.

```
class SOChatEvent
     class << self; attr_accessor :events; end
     @events = []

      @@event_parser = {
                                0 => SOChatSubClass, #hypothetical example for testing
                                1 => SOChatMessage,
                                2 => SOChatMessageEdit,
                                #etc
                              }
    def self.create_from_evt( json_event_data, room=nil, server=nil)
      event_type = json_event_data["event_type"]
      event_class =  @@event_parser[event_type]
      #this creates the class defined by class returned in the @@event_parser hash
      event_obj = event_class.new(json_event_data, room, server)
    end

    #rest of class
end
```

`@@event_parser` contains the mapping between event type and the class to implement that event type.  You just assign the appropriate class to a variable and treat it just like the actual class.

Code like the following would create an object of the appropriate class:

```
event_obj = SOChatEvent.create_from_evt( json_event_data,
                                        "some room", 
                                        "some server")
```

Note: There are further optimizations that could be done to what I provided to be even cleaner and more concise, but hopefully this helps you get over the hump of the case statement.

Edit: I forgot to mention the Class instance variable `SOChatEvent.events` created with this: 
`class << self; attr_accessor :events; end
         @events = []`

You were pushing events to an event stack, but I wasn't clear where you wanted that stack to exist and whether it was a global events list, or specific to a particular class. The one I did is global, so feel free to change it if you wanted the event stack constrained to certain classes or instances.

Comment: *Awecome*, Thanks @forforf! This question was getting no love :-) Your code is much cleaner. The events "stack" is actually just an array, which has functions for pulling the events out for each room. It should not be global

Comment: [Read the source for SOChatEventCollection in Trac](http://trac.digitalfruition.com/soxmpp/browser/trunk/classes/SOChatEventCollection.rb). Basically it keeps the events in an internal structure like this: `@my_events_by_server[server][room.room_id].push(event)` and then allows me to pull just events for one room.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then just ignore that part and stick with what you have.